Is Evil eligible to find his true love?
What does scriptures say about soulmates for Evil?
Can an Evil have a soulmate? Imagine a person (human) who has done horrible crimes in his lifetime - have god assigned him a partner before his birth? Is he now cursed (or ineligible) to not be able to ever find a soulmate?
Did Asurs have soulmates/partners?
Can an Asur or an Human who has done a horrible crime ever find true love?
Does the scripture say something like - “they will find a namesake partner but never find true love”?
